# Mysql data filteration

Tags: mysql

```
Id Conversationid    Agentid    Event       Timestamp
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1      1234          aaditya    ASSIGN      2018-08-02 09:19:50
2      1234          aaditya    REPLY       2018-08-02 09:24:46
3      1234          rehman     ASSIGN      2018-08-02 09:25:39
4      2345           pavan     ASSIGN      2018-08-03 11:24:35
5      2345           pavan     REPLY       2018-08-03 11:25:53
6      3456          sanjay     ASSIGN      2018-08-02 13:19:02
7      3456          sanjay     REPLY       2018-08-02 13:20:33
8      4567           rahul    ASSIGN       2018-08-05 04:49:54
9      4567           rahul    REPLY        2018-08-05 04:55:54
10     4567           rahul    ASSIGN       2018-08-05 04:49:54
```

I have a dataset as above. i want the id's where for a conversationid is assigned to an agent who has both Assign and reply events and the difference b/w the two is more than 5 mins.
I.e. from the above dataset output should be details of id's 1,2 and also 8 and 9

Comment: Show us what you have done already. Put the query that you tried.

Comment: select S.* from 
(select * from Conversation_State_Tracker where conversationid in (select conversationid from Conversation_State_Tracker where conversationid in (select a.conversationid from (select conversationid,agentId,count(*) as c from `Conversation_State_Tracker` group by conversationid,agentId having c > 1) a) and state='REPLY_EVENT' ) ) as S
inner join 
(select conversationid,agentId from `Conversation_State_Tracker` group by conversationid,agentId having count(*)>1 ) as T on S.conversationid = T.conversationid and S.agentId = T.agentId  order by conversationid,agentid

Comment: now my question is how to find the time diff as there is one column timetamp and diff rows for assign and reply events for each conversationid agentid combination

Comment: Please edit your question; don't put queries into comments. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below query with use of TIMESTAMPDIFF() in MySQL

Note: - Time difference between id (1,2) is less than 5 mins.So we can expect only Id (8,9).

```
SELECT assigns.id AS AssignID, replies.id AS ReplyID, assigns.agentid AS Agentid
FROM
(SELECT id,agentid,TIMESTAMP FROM timeD WHERE EVENT = 'assign' GROUP BY TIMESTAMP) AS assigns
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id,agentid,TIMESTAMP FROM timeD WHERE EVENT = 'reply' GROUP BY TIMESTAMP) AS replies
ON assigns.agentid = replies.agentid 
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,assigns.TIMESTAMP,replies.TIMESTAMP) > 5;
```